# Send Email (Outlook 2016) via Powershell

Tags: powershell, email, outlook

i searched a lot and found lots of solutions like that:

```
$ol = New-Object -comObject Outlook.Application  
$mail = $ol.CreateItem(0)
$mail.Recipients.Add("empfänger@domain.com")
$mail.Subject = "Betreff: Info fuer den Empfaenger"
$mail.Body = "Hier können Sie Ihren Nachrichtentext übergeben. Gerne auch in Form einer Variablen. Ihre Informationen, sollten dann aber als Objekt-Typ STRING vorliegen."
$Mail.Send()
```

but it doesn't work. Know anyone this problem?

(Outlook is manually working; i am not searching an solution with smtp adress..)

Comment: _"it doesn't work"_.  What actually happens?  Nothing at all, error message, confirmation prompt, etc?

Comment: Sorry. Powershell just runs through without action and without error

Comment: The code works as it is.The issue resides in your particular case. Provide more details on the issue as "It doesn't work" is not providing even basic information.

Comment: I do not get any action or error message from powershell or outlook. Where else should I find details? Thanks for clues

Comment: You should specify what actions you did take to confirm the code is not working. As an example, Did you check empfänger@domain.com inbox and spam folder? did you check the mail server logs? did you try using a controlled outlook configuration so that you can reproduce the error in a controlled environment where you can check the mail server logs?

Comment: When Outlook is running at the same time, do you see the message being created?

Comment: @ Mike: I sended all mails to me to check the result. I checked also the spam folder. i have no access to the mail server logs. So i also don't can send mails with smtp adress and want to use the open Outlook instanz. @ Dmitry : Outlook is running at the same time and didn't create a Mail. For me the script does not handle outlook.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you faced with a security prompt/issue in Outlook. The `Send` method is sensitive, so if you automate Outlook for sending emails and calling the `Send` method in external applications, you may get security prompts. “Security” in this context refers to the so-called “object model guard” that triggers security prompts and blocks access to certain features in an effort to prevent malicious programs from harvesting email addresses from Outlook data and using Outlook to propagate viruses and spam. These prompts cannot simply be turned off, except in Outlook 2007 and above with an anti-virus application running.

To avoid security prompts or issues you can:

- Create a COM add-in and use the "safe" application instance which doesn't trigger security prompts or issues.
- Use a low-level code which doesn't trigger security prompts - Extended MAPI. Or just you may consider any wrapper around that API such as Redemption.
- Use the [Outlook Security Manager](https://www.add-in-express.com/outlook-security/index.php) component for suppressing such prompts or issues caused by the OOM.
- Set up a group policy to avoid prompts.
- Set up any up-to-date antivirus software.